# KCacheGrind Not Opening Anything on Fedora 17

Tags: fedora, kcachegrind

So, I've tried everything I can do right now, not really getting anywhere with this, so I am turning to the guys on SO for some assistance.

System Details:

Fedora 17 x86_64

Intel® Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2160 @ 1.80GHz × 2

1.9 GiB memory

KCacheGrind 0.7.1

KDE Platform Version 4.9.4

Procedure Details:
I get an XDEBUG log from the server or from a Chrome Ext called Xdebug Helper.  And I run it, either directly from the icon or from a Shell Script I created.

```
#!/bin/bash
export $(dbus-launch)
kcachegrind
```

And I get an error "No Profile Data Loaded"

Any ideas?

SORRY: error reads "(No function selected)"

Forgive me.  I am a n00b at Linux and KCacheGrind.

Answer (score 1):

I used root.  Fixed.  Adding 10 or more characters.

Comment: Fixed it for me using a cachegrind/callgrind generated by xdebug. Looks like the qcachegrind version 0.7.4 provided by brew suffers from this